# HttpURLConnection in Android , will they repeat automatically until connection success?

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, repeat

This is HttpURLConnection code, checking the internet connection. I just want to know will they repeat automatically until connection success? or do I need to specify any retry strategy explicitly

```
  HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection());
                urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
                urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(500); //choose your own timeframe
                urlc.setReadTimeout(500); //choose your own timeframe
                urlc.connect();
                int responseCode = urlc.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCode == 200) {
                    //if internet is up then execute the jobs
                 doSomeWork();
                } else {
                    Log.d("Warning", "Internet is not available");
                }
```

Comment: Use volley instead as volley have a retry strategy. And you need to write your own retry policy if you are using HttpURLConnection

Comment: nope `HttpURLConnection` does not gonna retry. yoou have to write your own retry policy and and take care of connection pool and connection property also how many time you have retry before giving up on network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpURLConnection doesn't have any retry policy. You need to handle it yourself.

You can use **getErrorStream()** method in HttpURLConnection class to check for errors including connection issues. If the connection to server was not established, it returns null.

Details can be found here - https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getErrorStream()